# JQVMap region Click Error

Tags: jquery, jqvmap

I have a JQVMap setup like this:

```
jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({
  map: 'usa_en',
  enableZoom: true,
  showTooltip: true,
  selectedRegion: 'MO',
  onRegionClick: function(element, code, region) {
    var message = 'You clicked "'
      + region
      + '" which has the code: '
      + code.toUpperCase();
    alert(message);
  },
});
```

When I click on any state I get the alert for the state as set up above, but I also get a JS error in the console:

> regionClickEvent is not defined

It is the `if (!regionClickEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) {` line in the JQVMap file, which is throwing the error. How can I get the state clicked on without throwing this error?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Found the solution, change line 466 in `jqvmap.js` file to:

```
regionClickEvent = $.Event('regionClick.jqvmap');

jQuery(params.container).trigger(regionClickEvent, [code, mapData.pathes[code].name]);
```