# JQVMAP selected regions deselect with JSFIDDLE Demo

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqvmap

Ok I have a [JQVMAP](http://jqvmap.com/) that I have on my site to select states for a search box. Everything worked great until I added my Clear function.

I also had to incorporate the patch from member HardCode [Link to the patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17459539/jqvmap-region-click-error/17460029#17460029)

> Found the solution, change line 466 in jqvmap.js file to:
>
> ```
> regionClickEvent = $.Event('regionClick.jqvmap');
>
> jQuery(params.container).trigger(regionClickEvent, [code, mapData.pathes[code].name]);
> ```

This is how I initialize it:

```
// with this Code it will select states and change the color of selected states plus save the codes of selected states into a hidden field

$('#omap').vectorMap(
    {
        map: 'usa_en',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderColor: '#000',
        borderWidth: 4,
        color: '#f4f3f0',
        enableZoom: false,
        hoverColor: '#fece2f',
        hoverOpacity: null,
        normalizeFunction: 'linear',
        scaleColors: ['#b6d6ff', '#005ace'],
        selectedColor: '#db9b15',
        selectedRegion: null,
        showTooltip: true,
        multiSelectRegion: true,
        onRegionClick: function(element, code, region) {
            if(highlight[code]!=='#db9b15'){
                highlight[code]='#db9b15';
                origin = $('#search_origin_states');
                states = origin.val();
                if (states == ""){
                    origin.val(code);
                } else {
                    origin.val(states + "," + code);
                }
            } else {
                highlight[code]='#f4f3f0';
                states = origin.val();
                if (states.indexOf(","+code) >= 0) {
                    states = states.replace(","+code,"");
                    origin.val(states);
                } else if (states.indexOf(code+",") >= 0){
                    states = states.replace(code+",","");
                    origin.val(states);
                } else {
                    states = states.replace(code,"");
                    origin.val(states);
                }
            }
            $('#omap').vectorMap('set', 'colors', highlight);
        }
    });
```

I use to have to click each state to clear it. But I wrote a script to clear all in one click.

```
function search_map_clear(field, map) {
    var states = $('#search_' + field + '_states');
    var sel_states = states.val();
    var highlight2 = [];
    $.each(sel_states.split(','), function (i, code) {
        highlight2[code] = '#f4f3f0';
        $('#' + map).vectorMap('set', 'colors', highlight2);
    });
    states.val("");
}
```

This will change all colors back to the original color, but apparently it does not clear the `selectedRegions` because after clearing if I select any other state all the states that I changed back to original color show back up.

### My Question is:

How can I clear the selected states so were I can select different ones without clicking on every state that was selected prior

### UPDATE

I have been able to run this command from the console and I can select and deselect states... But it will not deselect a state that was clicked on to select.

```
$('#omap').vectorMap('select', 'ar');

$('#omap').vectorMap('deselect', 'ar');
```

I need to clear out the states that have been clicked on...

Here is my jsFiddle that will show you what is happening:

### [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BigAL83/9b4x69zo/)

Comment: That fiddle’s difficult to work with: it complains about the `<script>` tags on any edits to the HTML area, the external jqvmap resources are loaded in the wrong order (I see `TypeError: jQuery.fn.vectorMap is not a function` on page load), and is @HardCode’s patch included in the scripts you’re linking from jqvmap.com? Fixing those things up would probably yield more help…

Comment: you can access my page directly @ http://www.transportunl.com  just create a username and password... anything and it will take you to my search... it is on the left either origin or destination... I would give demo creditials but not sure how many people would wanna try...

Comment: everything is incorporated on my website it is still being developed... so database will be cleared when finished.  if you need to see the text box with the selected states... change the hidden field to text. it is right below the map.

Comment: Clear link is working fine for me. whats the problem?

Comment: after you click the clear link try to select another state. it will highlight all the other states too...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You store information in the variable `highlight`, and you clean the map with `highlight2`. It will not change the information in `highlight` so that when you trigger `onRegionClick()` it will change back to what you select.

Use global variable to let the scope of `highlight` to cross two script, then replace `highlight2` by `highlight` and remove `highlight2` declation.

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssk7833/9b4x69zo/5/) here, I think this is what you want.

Comment: `highlight1` goes with `omap` Origin map and `highlight2` goes with `dmap` Destination map.  they are 2 seperate maps on same page.

Comment: Your jsfiddle is working correctly... and that is what i want

Comment: I will award the points when it will allow me too. that was a simple fix. now i just need to seperate out a different one for Origin and one for destination that is why i had it as a local variable. but will figure it out.

Comment: Are you success now? If you still have any problems, ask it.
I don't see the website you designed updated.

Comment: I have it incorporated locally i will push it live in a few minutes..  i just duplicated the function and seperated the highlights completely... still have an hour before i can award the points

Answer (score 3):

I just added this function to library

```
setSelectedRegions: function(keys){
    for (var key in this.countries) {
        this.deselect(key, undefined);
    }
    var array = keys.split(",");

    for (i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
        //alert(array[i])
        this.select(array[i], undefined);
    }
},
```

and used it later as

```
jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap('set', 'selectedRegions', 'gb,us');
```